# How to make an asynchronous spring batch job with in another job

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am trying to create an **Spring batch** asynchronous job with in another job. Say Job-1 should be completed and Job-2 should be executed. But problem is Job-1 is waiting till Job-2 is getting completed which i don't want. I have used JobStep as well but it is happening in an synchronous way and not helpful. Can some one help me how to use Asynchronously where Job-1 should not wait till Job-2 is completed ?
Sample xml snippet below

```
<bean id="taskExecutorAsync" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />
<bean id="jobLauncherAsync" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
        <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutorAsync" />
</bean>

<bean id="CreationProcess" class="test.CreationProcess">
        <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncherAsync" />
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
        <property name="jobExplorer" ref="jobExplorer" />           
</bean>
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider adding a short fragment of your code to show how you are putting the things together – it will improve your odds of getting help here!

Comment: Thanks lenz. I have added sample xml snippet from the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor executor to avoid blocking.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a separate thread, returned back and new thread updated the details. Unable to create a new asynchronous spring batch job with in another job.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't using the `JobStep`. The reason is because a `Job` is a state machine with each `Step` serving as a state.  In order for the `Job` to transition to the next state (aka complete in your use case), the current state (your child job) needs to complete.

You can launch jobs from other jobs, but to do so, you'll need to write a `Tasklet` to launch the job on a new thread (using a `TaskExecutor`) and return immediately.